# Release website not recognising reference

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-server

My local website works fine.

I have uploaded the website to the server. All of the DLLs are in the bin directory, but I still get the missing reference error as you can see in the following image:

[image: Error]

The 'missing' reference is not directly used by the website, but rather is required by a library that the website uses.

My configurations are:

Server:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 x64
- IIS 8
- .NET 4.5

Local:

- Windows 8.1 Pro x64
- Visual Studio 2013 Pro
- IIS Express

Comment: The "incorrect format" error usually means you're trying to load an x64 library in a x86 application or vice versa. Please use the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeCaster gave the hint above. The website was set to run as x64, but was trying to load a x86 binary.

To fix this, I:

- Highlighted the website's application pool
- Clicked 'Advanced Settings'
- Set 'Enable 32-bit Applications' to true

[image]